# Function not working while code does

Tags: r, function

So I have a little issue with a function. As I have another very similar function that works, I'm not understanding the issue.
The function that does not work:

```
datamerge <- function(country_name){
fulldata$AoN[which(fulldata$country==country_name)] <- AoN$AvgOfN[which(AoN$countryFD==country_name)]
}
```

When running `datamerge("Afghanistan")` Nothing happens.

But this works:

```
fulldata$AoN[which(fulldata$country=="Afghanistan")] <- AoN$AvgOfN[which(AoN$countryFD=="Afghanistan")]
```

I just don't want to do that for all 185 countries in my sample.

Thank you
Magnus

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Please post a reproducible example. It is unclear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: In R, you should think about the value your function returns, not the operations it performs. If you modify the input inside the function, it has no effect on the original input typically. If you really want it to, there is the `<<-` operator... but you should probably just start thinking in terms of functional programming. Anyway, for your application, you should use a loop, not a function, I reckon.

Answer (score 0):

Your function works fine, it just doesn't return anything.

http://cran.r-project.org/doc//manuals/R-intro.html#Writing-your-own-functions